# Proper way to end request in CakePHP 2.6 in beforeFilter

Tags: cakephp, before-filter

In CakePHP 2.6, sometimes i want to end the current request in the `beforeFilter()` callback, and maybe issue a forbidden or not found result status.

In a controller action i know i can do this by returning the `CakeResponse`object but i want to this in the callback. Is there a proper CakePHP way of doing so, to ensure all callbacks are called and the app is properly processed, or can i just send the headers and call `die()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By throwing exceptions you do exactly that. Nothing else necessary:

```
throw new ForbiddenException();
```

or

```
throw new NotFoundException();
```

etc.

That is a clean way to bail early. The error/exception handler will automatically format it in the necessary output format (html, json, xml, ...) for you and will send the right headers (status code, ...).

Never use die()/exit. Never send headers manually. It makes your code untestable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried if returning the CakeResponse object in the beforeFilter() works the same way? If not see [CakeResponse::send()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-CakeResponse.html#_send) and [Object::_stop()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Object.html#__stop) and do this:

```
$this->response->body('whatever you need here');
$this->response->send();
$this->_stop();
```

Comment: Returning CakeResponse doesn't work. I've tried it. I will try your sugestion.